# Prevent duplicate page on plugin activation (Or unpublish a page on plugin deactivation)

Tags: wordpress

I'm using something like this to add a page when my Wordpress plugin is activated.

```
function create_wordpress_pages(){

$my_post = array();
$my_post['post_title'] = 'My post';
$my_post['post_content'] = 'This is my post.';
$my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
$my_post['post_author'] = 1;
$my_post['post_type'] = 'page';

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_wordpress_pages');
```

This is fine (and dandy) but I don't want to re-create this page every time this plugin is deactivated. How do I check to see if this page exists OR unpublish on plugin deactivation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the page exists using WP_Query. Simple as that.
To delete on deactivation, use [register_deactivation_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook).